# Apache Kafka integration to APIGEE gateway

Tags: apache-kafka, apigee

I'm new to Apigee gateway. Is possible to integrate Kafka with APIGEE gateway for publish and subscribe. I need to subscribe Kafka topic from Apigee routing to route a message to different back end system. I mean the router should behave like a consumer of Kafka messages.

Please help on this